# JAXB Map with Lists

Tags: xml, list, dictionary, jaxb

I must apologize, I swore to my self not asking this since is a common subject but despite all the similar questions I'm still having issues.

**Update:** I found some errors in my code that I fixed but it keeps failing. I updated the post to reflect the last changes.

**Update 2:** I decided to simplify the code, instead of using methods to set the attributes I change all of them to public and get rid of the methods. Right now it compiles and run without an issue but the resulting Map is empty. This is the new code.

```
public class BCLURLClearanceIssuer
{
private File xml = null;
private JAXBContext aJAXBContext = null;
private Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
private BCLURLRestrictions aURLRestrictionList = null;

public BCLURLClearanceIssuer()
    {
    this.xml = new File("/www/hosts/www.bucle.co/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/BCLURLRestrictions.xml");
    try{
        this.aJAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BCLURLRestrictions.class);
        }
    catch (JAXBException e)
        {
         System.out.println(e);
        }
    try
        {
        this.unmarshaller = aJAXBContext.createUnmarshaller();
        }
    catch (JAXBException e2)
        {
        System.out.println(e2);
        }

        unmarshaller.setAdapter(new BCLMapAdapter());
    try
        {
        this.aURLRestrictionList = (BCLURLRestrictions) unmarshaller.unmarshal(this.xml);
        }
    catch(JAXBException e3)
        {
        System.out.println(e3);
        }
    }

public Map<String,BCLURLRestriction> getRestrictions()
    {
    return this.aURLRestrictionList.getRestrictions();
    }
}
```

My goal is to read an XML file like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BCLURLRestrictions>
<restriction>
    <appName>app1</appName>
    <url>/apps/app1/</url>
    <page>app1.html</page>
    <page>app1b.html</page>
</restriction>
<restriction>
    <appName>app2</appName>
    <url>/apps/app2/</url>
    <page>app2.html</page>
</restriction>
</BCLURLRestrictions>
```

These are the classes involved.

BCLURLRestriction.java

```
public class BCLURLRestriction
    {

    @XmlElement(name = "AppName")
    public String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "url")
    public List<String> urls;

    @XmlElement(name = "page")
    public List<String> pages;


    }
```

BCLURLRestrictions.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "BCLURLRestrictions")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BCLURLRestrictions
{

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BCLMapAdapter.class)
public Map <String,BCLURLRestriction> restrictionMap = new HashMap<String,BCLURLRestriction>();

public Map <String,BCLURLRestriction>  getRestrictionMap()
    {
    return this.restrictionMap;
    }

public void  setRestrictionMap(Map aMap)
    {
    this.restrictionMap = aMap;
    }
}
```

BCLURLRestrictionListType.java

```
public class BCLURLRestrictionsListType 
{


public List <BCLURLRestriction> restrictionsList = new ArrayList<BCLURLRestriction>();

public BCLURLRestrictionsListType()
    {
    }

}
```

BCLMapAdapter.java

```
public class BCLMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<BCLURLRestrictionsListType,Map<String,BCLURLRestriction>> 
{

public BCLMapAdapter()
    {

    }

public Map<String,BCLURLRestriction> unmarshal(BCLURLRestrictionsListType aRestrictionListType) throws Exception 
    {
    HashMap<String,BCLURLRestriction> aRestrictionMap = new HashMap<String,BCLURLRestriction>();
    for(BCLURLRestriction aRestriction: aRestrictionListType.restrictionsList)
        {
        aRestrictionMap.put(aRestriction.name,aRestriction);
        }
    return aRestrictionMap;
    }


public BCLURLRestrictionsListType marshal(Map<String,BCLURLRestriction> aRestrictionMap) throws Exception
    {
    BCLURLRestrictionsListType aRestrictionsListType = new BCLURLRestrictionsListType();
    for(Entry<String, BCLURLRestriction> aRestrictionEntry: aRestrictionMap.entrySet())
        {
        BCLURLRestriction aRestriction = new BCLURLRestriction();
        aRestriction.name = aRestrictionEntry.getValue().name;
        aRestriction.urls = aRestrictionEntry.getValue().urls;
        aRestriction.pages = aRestrictionEntry.getValue().pages;
        aRestrictionsListType.restrictionsList.add(aRestriction);
        }

    return aRestrictionsListType;
    }


}
```

Suggestions are all welcome!

Comment: Also, can we see the code you use to get your JAXB context and do  your unmarshalling?

Comment: There won't be likely any *visible* exceptions seen with this type of exception handling: `catch (JAXBException e){}`. Surely you're kidding about this, right?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. I just added it and there is no output. The only thing I get is null pointer exception on the web server but it points me to the part where I created a new BCLURLClearanceIssuer. Maybe I'm inducing an infinite loop?

Comment: I was looking at the wrong log file, now I am seeing things... I'm gonna put the log in the main post. Thanks for being "outside the box" I will check into the error log and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe that the propOrder annotation element needs to list Strings that match the class's JavaBeans properties and doesn't care or look at the Strings you use to rename your schema elements.

Comment: And you're welcome. I am learning JAXB myself right now so may not be the best resource, certainly not as good as @BlaiseDoughan. Check out some of his stuff to learn a lot about JAXB.

Comment: yeah you were right, I thought it was the other way around. Also the XML file didn't have the right closing tag and in order for JAXB to understand the uppercase root tag I had to add @XmlRootElement(name="BCLURLRestriction"). You should put that on an answer to rank you up and delete the comment.